# Best way to import database in python project

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a python app that connects to a few different databases.  I would like different packages in my project to be able to use the database functions.  Instead of creating database logic in each of the packages, how can I create a "Global" package that I can use?  Here is an example of the structure I'm thinking of using:

```
main.py
    package1/
        __init__.py
        stuff1.py
        stuff2.py
    package2/
        __init__.py
        moar1.py
        moar2.py
    database/
        __init__.py
        dbfunctions.py
```

I would like to be able to use the database functions in the stuff and moar files without calling them from main.py.  I would like to be able to write the database logic, sql, etc in the packages and run them independently based on calls from main.py.

**Question:  How do I import the database functions into package1 and package2?  I would like to import the database items from the sibling directory.**

(also, I am way more familiar with using PHP and just starting out with python, so if I am going down completely down the wrong path I haven't started writing the app yet.  totally open to different structure suggestions.)

Comment: Have you tried the above solution, and if yes what problem do you have exactly ?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I forgot to ask my question.  Bolded above.

Comment: Test it out and report back with a **specific** question or problem.

Comment: I think I did.  How do I import the database functions from the sibling directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import from a sibling directory, sibling packages need to be part of a parent package.

Change your layout to:

```
wholeproject/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    package1/
        __init__.py
        stuff1.py
        stuff2.py
    package2/
        __init__.py
        moar1.py
        moar2.py
    database/
        __init__.py
        dbfunctions.py
```

and then, in main.py, you can import stuff and moar like this:

```
from wholeproject.package1 import stuff1
from wholeproject.package2 import moar1
```

and in stuff1 you can get dbfunctions like this:

```
from wholeproject.database import dbfunctions
```

Or you can grab individual functions as needed ... but this should get you started. You almost had it!

Comment: AH, I didn't know I had to create a package for the parent... thank you!